# Trying to make a mod application command that dm's the user asking questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I'm not sure how to dm the interactor in my code. It's in a cog and in a view class for a button

### My code-

```
# Buttons for the embed
class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @button(label="Apply Here!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def apply(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: Button):
        await interaction.response.defer() 

        user=interaction.user.id
        await interaction.followup.send(content="Please await a dm from the bot!", ephemeral=True)
# Here is where I want to send the message
        await DMChannel.send(content="Hello")
       
# Actual command 
class ModApp(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("modapp.py is ready!")
    
    @admin()
    @commands.hybrid_command(name="modapp", description="modapp embed")
    async def modapp(self, ctx):
        embedModApp=discord.Embed(title="Moderator Applications")
        embedModApp.set_author(name=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
        view=MyView()
        view.message=(
            await ctx.send(embed=embedModApp, view=view))

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(ModApp(client))
```

please tell me how to dm a user and how I can ask multiple questions and save the responses.

Comment: You can use `await user.send(content="hello")` to send a private message

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.send). In your code, [DMChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.DMChannel) is a class object in `discord.py`. You are looking to send a [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member) a message, which you can do by using the method [user.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.send).

```
async def button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
     user = interaction.user #  command user
     await user.send(content=“Hello!”)
```

Take a moment to read some of the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) on [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member), [discord.Interaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.Interaction).